# How do i call subclass method from superclass when using class hierarchy in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols

**Here is my code:**

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController{

}
-(IBAction)btnDetail1_Clicked:(id)sender;
@end



@implementation RootViewController

-(IBAction)btnDetail1_Clicked:(id)sender{
    DetailViewController1 *mvcr = [[DetailViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController1" bundle:nil];
    [mvcr setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvcr animated:YES];
    [mvcr release];
}
@end



@protocol NotifySubclass
@optional
-(void) serviceCall_done;
@end

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController{
     id<NotifySubclass> delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
-(void) initCallService;
@end




@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void) initCallService{
    "My some other code is here."
    [self performSelector:@selector(startLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void) startLoading{
    "My some other code is here."
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void) loadComplete{
    "I want to call DetailViewController1's "serviceCall_done" method from here.
     [delegate serviceCall_done];
}
@end



@interface DetailViewController1 : MasterViewController <NotifySubclass>{

}
@end




@implementation DetailViewController1
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [self initCallService];
}

-(void) serviceCall_done{

}
@end
```

I want to call `DetailViewController1`'s `serviceCall_done` method from `loadCompete` method of `MasterViewController`.

I had tried creating protocol but not getting where exactly i have to write the protocol as I am calling `DetailViewController1` from `RootViewController`.

Can anyone guide me for this ?

Comment: You're confusing your question (and code) by talking about notifying "subclasses" and "superclasses". This question doesn't have anything to do with class inheritance; you simply need a reference to your detail controller in your master controller. Is there some object that knows about both of these, perhaps your root view controller?

Comment: @jrturton I have multiple detailviewcontroller like DetailViewController1, DetailViewController2, DetailViewController3 etc.They all are subclass of MasterViewController. Which detailviewcontroller to notify that i will manage but how to notify that I am asking. Can you please elaborate in more detail.

Comment: I wish Apple makes a warning for words `retain` and `delegate` being part of a single expression.

Comment: @A-Live, I think it would be enough, if the compile would warn about it. I dont expect Apple to call me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for this Post Notification and add observer in all 3 details class. Read some tutorials about NSNotificationCenter.

Here are some tutorials

[Tutorail 1](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/dead-simple-nsnotification-example-iphone/)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/16267-NSNotificationCenter-Example.html)

[Tutorial 3](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/16/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial-using-the-notification-center-in-your-iphone-app/)

Comment: Thanks Rahul Vyas to answer. It helps me.

Answer (score 2):

Add a method in `MasterViewController`

```
-(void) serviceCall_done{
    //in this method you do nothing.
}
```

**Modify**

```
-(void) loadComplete{
    [self serviceCall_done];
}
```

And then, In `DetailViewController1` override this method `serviceCall_done`

```
-(void) serviceCall_done{
    //Add code
}
```